# Node JS + Mongo DB: ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I am trying to Save/Create a New Document (User) to Mongo DB using Mongoose, I am getting the following Validation Error in spite of providing all the Values with proper DataType:

**ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required.**

I am a Beginner at Node JS and Mongo DB. Hence I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

I have also added the following modules:

- Express
- Mongo
- Mongoose
- Body Parser

Please see below for more details:

**Detailed Error:**

```
{
"errors": {
    "username": {
        "message": "Path `username` is required.",
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "properties": {
            "type": "required",
            "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
            "path": "username"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "username",
        "$isValidatorError": true
    }
},
"_message": "User validation failed",
"message": "User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required.",
"name": "ValidationError"
}
```

**User Schema / Model:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});

mongoose.model("User", userSchema, "users");
```

**User Controller:**

```
var register = function (req, res) {

console.log("Registering User.");

var firstName = req.body.firstname;
var lastName = req.body.lastname;
var userName = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

User
    .create({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        userName: userName,
        password: password
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error creating User: ", err);
            res
                .status(400)
                .json(err)
        } else {
            console.log("User Created: ", user);
            res
                .status(201)
                .json(user)
        }
    })
};
```

I just don't understand, why I am getting this Validation Error.
Can anybody please guide me through this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Property names are case sensitive. You're passing in "userName" instead of "username."

Comment: Ohhhhh God......
That was such a Silly Mistake.
Thank you so Much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
User
    .create({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        username: userName, // the property is "username" in model
        password: password
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error creating User: ", err);
            res
                .status(400)
                .json(err)
        } else {
            console.log("User Created: ", user);
            res
            .status(201)
            .json(user)
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did have this problem and the way to solve it just to add these lines in your server.js:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
```

and make sure to install Cors and Express.

My problem was that I didn't add just this line:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

After adding it, data was saved perfectly.